# PHP Testing JSON Contains with SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, sqlite

My Web App uses Laravel & MySQL but for my tests I am using SQLite in memory.

This is my code that I use in my Controller:

```
$opportunities = DB::table('opportunities')
        ->whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(businesses, \'"' . $business . '"\')')
        ->get();
```

When testing this throws an exception because of how SQLite doesn't have a JSON_CONTAINS function. How can I get around this so that my tests pass and I don't have to make any massive changes to the structure? Does SQLite have a function for this or something along these lines?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use MySQL's JSON feature. Stick to standard SQL features that are in both MySQL and SQLite.

Comment: But it really makes little sense to use a different DBMS for testing than production. If your testing succeeds, you don't know that it will work in production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could emulate `JSON_CONTAINS` during testing using [`sqlite_create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-create-function.php) e.g.

```
function json_contains($json, $val) {
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
  // trim double quotes from around the value to match MySQL behaviour
  $val = trim($val, '"');
  // this will work for a single dimension JSON value, if more dimensions
  // something more sophisticated will be required
  // that is left as an exercise for the reader
  return in_array($val, $array);
}

sqlite_create_function(<your db handle>, 'JSON_CONTAINS', 'json_contains');
```

You may also want to emulate the optional third parameter of `JSON_CONTAINS` e.g.

```
function json_contains($json, $val, $path = null) {
  $array = json_decode($json, true);
  // trim double quotes from around the value to match MySQL behaviour
  $val = trim($val, '"');
  // this will work for a single dimension JSON value, if more dimensions
  // something more sophisticated will be required
  // that is left as an exercise for the reader
  if ($path)
    return $array[$path] == $val;
  else
    return in_array($val, $array);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! You might want to add `$val = trim($val, '"');` to the function so there is better compatibility because MySQL strips them automatically, PHP doesn't.

Comment: @Shiv good point, I will edit the answer. Also just noticed a typo in the second version if you use that, I had `=` instead of `==` in the `$array[$path]` comparison.

Answer (score 9):

A bit more explanation for the accepted answer:

```
/**
 * Call this method in your test. 
 * @PHP 7.4+
 */
private function setupSqlite(): void
{
    DB::connection()->getPdo()->sqliteCreateFunction('JSON_CONTAINS', function ($json, $val, $path = null) {
        $array = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        // trim double quotes from around the value to match MySQL behaviour
        $val = trim($val, '"');
        // this will work for a single dimension JSON value, if more dimensions
        // something more sophisticated will be required
        // that is left as an exercise for the reader
        if ($path) {
            return $array[$path] == $val;
        }

        return in_array($val, $array, true);
    });
```

Then you can use this query, that works for both mysql/mariadb and sqlite:

```
$result = Product::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(tags, \'"' . $tag . '"\')')->get();
```

In above example I was searching json column with simple array:

```
$column = ["example", "test", "simple"];
```

Comment: That's a useful addition to the question.

Comment: Good answer.  Note, this doesn't seem to work with the built-in Laravel `->whereJsonContains('audience', NewsItem::PUBLIC)`, rather it seems to only be happy with the raw statement as @MultiHunter notes in the query example above.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on running my test suite on SQLite because there are just too many differences between the implementations. The first issue was it's lack of support for enums, but when even simple things like `ALTER` statements were causing problems I changed to MySQL for testing too.

What I do now is specify the name of my testing db in `phpunit.xml`.

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="mydb_testing"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

The down side of this is being required to create two databases to develop the app, but I need to be sure that the migrations will work on production, which uses MySQL and testing on SQLite doesn't prove that.